# How to define router type use typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation

I'm using router array, and i want to typescript tips when i add route item.
now it can tip me, but when i use props.navigate it will tip error, and component show error if not set as any

can someone help me the typescript, ths

my code:

```js
// types.ts
import { StackNavigationProp, StackNavigationState, ParamListBase } from ‘@react-navigation/stack’;
import { RouteProp, StackNavigationOptions, StackNavvigationEventMap } from '@react-navigation/native';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Settings: undefined;
};

export type INavigationType<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> = 
  StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
  
export type IRouteType<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  RouteProp<RootStackParamList, T>;
  
export type IStackRouteType = 
  RouteConfig<
    RootStackParamList,
    keyof RootStackParamList ,
    StackNavigationState<ParamListBase>,
    StackNavigationOptions,
    StackNavvigationEventMap
  >
```

```js
// index.tsx
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { IStackRouteType } from './types;'


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const stackRoutes: IStackRouteType= [
  {
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeScreen,
    options: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Profile',
    component: ProfileScreen,  // <----- error
    options: {
      headerShown: false
    },
    listeners: () => {
       return ({
         state: (e) => {
            console.log('state changed', e.data);
         }, 
       })
    }
  },
   {
    name: 'Settings',
    component: Settings,
    options: {
      headerShown: false
    }
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator.Navigator>
        {stackRoutes.map((route, index) => (
          <StackNavigator.Screen
            key={route.name}
            {...route}
          />
        ))}
      </StackNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

```js
// Profile page
import { INavigationType, IRouteType } from '../types';

interface IProps {
  route: IRouteType<'Profile'>;
  navigation: INavigationType<'Profile'>;
}
function Profile ({
route,
navigation
}: IProps ) {
  const { userId } = route.params;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.navigate(PageName) // this not tip pageName or page arguments if the page need
  }, [])


  return (
    <Text>this is Profile page</Text>
  )
}
```

https://snack.expo.dev/wPNH-AqjY

use props.navigation() it can be tip pageName and arguments right
component: PageComponent will not error if not as any

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the hook approach with [useNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) and [typescript annotation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/)
You already have `RootStackParamList` defined so you just need to do:

```
  import {useNavigation} from 'react-navigation/core'

  type RootStackProps =
  StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;
  const navigation = useNavigation<RootStackProps>();

  navigation.navigate('Profile') <--- this tips route and args
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Due to the way of development, our navigator has been separated into an independent module, so I still need to use arrays to combine routers, and more in the way of props